# If the Terminator had killed Sarah Connor in 1984, would he have gone on a mass killing spree until he was destroyed?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

If the Terminator had completed his mission in 1984 by killing Sarah Connor, is it likely that he would have gone on a mass killing spree until he was destroyed by the police/military?

In other words, did Skynet give him a secondary mission other than just killing Sarah Conner and what was that mission?